# Javascript: How to make a circle clickable so that it redirects to a different page?

Tags: javascript

I have created two html pages and I want to link the two pages through a click-able circle. I want to make a circle click-able so that the current window is replaced by a new window.

Comment: did you try a search????

Comment: try to share little few code for more understand your context

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

```
function goToPage(page) {
  location.replace(page);
}

goToPage("http://example.com/page1");
```